# how to calculate students total marks in django using total function and sort

Tags: python, django, django-models

**model class**

from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):

```
Name = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
Roll_no = models.IntegerField(default = 0 , unique = True )
Emailid = models.EmailField(max_length=54 )
Submrk1 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
Submrk2 = models.PositiveIntegerField() 
Submrk3 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
Total = models.IntegerField(default = total)


def __str__(self):
    return self.Name + self.Total

def total(self):

    self.Total = self.Submrk1 + self.Submrk2  + self.Submrk3
    
    return self.Total
```

**views**

from django.shortcuts import render , redirect
from .models import Student
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect

def liststu(request):

```
student = Student.objects.all()

return render(request, 'liststu.html',{'student': student})
```

def Createstu(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    name = request.POST.get('name')
    rollno = request.POST.get('rollno')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    sub1 = request.POST.get('sub1')
    sub2 = request.POST.get('sub2')
    sub3 = request.POST.get('sub3')

    stu = Student.objects.create(Name = name,Roll_no = rollno, Emailid = email, Submrk1 = sub1, Submrk2 = sub2 , Submrk3 = sub3)

    return HttpResponseRedirect('list')

else:

    return render(request, 'create.html')
```

def sort(request):

```
ctx = Student.objects.order_by('Total')

return  render(request, 'liststu.html' , {'student':ctx})
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the total of marks you can either:

1. Update the `total` field every time you student is saved by overriding the `.save()` function, e.g.

   ```py
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.total = self.get_total
      super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
   ```
2. Use Django annotation to add the total by adding together your marks:

   ```py
   from django.db.models import F

   students = Student.objects.annotate(total=F('Submrk1')+F('Submrk2')+F('Submrk3'))
   ```

However, note that you can't annotate `total` if that's already a model field. You also shouldn't create a model method that conflicts with an existing field (again, `total`).

As an aside, I would suggest creating a separate model for your marks which would allow you create any number of marks whilst still using annotation to get the total.